# How to 2d bin in histogram python

Tags: python, image, histogram, binning, histogram2d

I m a student and I m in a huge trouble, I am trying to visualize a plot of 2 variables x and y
the number of data points in x and y are like 100 thousand or similar and the data in is float and almost with 3 decimal placesfoe eg 0.002 or 12.003.

When i try to plot it using plt.hist i get weird lines in my plot when i give it different bins sometimes some bins work perfect. I have attached the image of plot and code below pls help.
[Like this one is perfect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x4tC.jpg)
[One line appears here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkLXa.jpg)

[More lines appear here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCVTk.jpg)

and so on..
**it just happens when i increase binning number in my code like bins =[46,46] and bins =[47,47] and so on and then there will be a specific bin number where it would appear okayish and perfect i dont know why this is happening**

```
plt.hist2d(df3.Yaxis, df3.YError,bins =[45,45])
plt.colorbar()
plt.title("EMF OFF X- axis")
plt.xlabel("mm")
plt.show()
```

Pls help me explain this

I tried many other libraries in python all have the same problem while plotting.
I tried to do the same stuff in matlab and it works flawlessly
but pls make me understand why python is like this

Comment: you can try defining a third argument `range`, which edges is specified for the bins along each dimension, and is defined as an array of 2 element arrays `[[xmin, xmax], [ymin, ymax]]` you should go testing using the length of x and y as minimum greater than 0 and maximum less than length or some value of `[x, y]`

Comment: OK i tried but it just keeps making it worse